# Adding new UUID foreign key into existing table using laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, uuid

I want to add new column in my `users` table which is uuid so here is the code

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('uuid')->nullable()->unique();
});
```

and then i want to make a relation using foreign key in my `skills` table, and in this `skills` table already has foreign key from another table but it always showing error `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

```
Schema::table('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('user_id')
         ->references('uuid')
         ->on('users')
         ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

is it posible i cant add new foreign key just because i havent drop and redeclare the existing foreign key ? why i ask that is because when i add uuid foreign key in my `trainings` table that has no foreign key at all is success here is the code

```
Schema::table('trainings', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('uuid')->on('users');
});
```

here is the error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_masteremployee`.`skills` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `skills` add constraint `skills_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`uuid`) on delete cascade)

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: `foreignUuid` creates a field and creates a foreign constraint for it ("Create a new UUID column on the table with a foreign key constraint."), btw

Comment: yes i know that @lagbox i already can make a foreignUuid in table `trainings` but i cant make it in `skills` table i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its because the `uuid` is not a primary key so i decided to use this instead

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->dropPrimary('id');
     $table->uuid('uuid')->nullable()->unique();
     $table->primary(['id','uuid']);
});
```

and if you dont want to drop the existing primary key, you can just make a simple column and make your self a relation BelongsTo() / HasMany() in the model

```
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('uuid')->nullable();
    });

    Schema::table('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable();
    });
```

the relation code

```
 public function skills(): Hasmany
{
    return $this->hasmany(Skills::class, 'user_id', 'uuid');
}
```